# Yii2 how to make this query in model?

Tags: php, html, mysql, yii2

I have two tables; applicant_rating (AR) and applicant_rating_score (ARS). I have made a dropdown menu using the values in applicant_rating:

```
<?= $form->field($model,'rating_id')->dropDownList(Applicant::getApplicantRatingNames(),['prompt' => 'Please select']);?>
```

This is the function being called in the model:

```
public function getApplicantRatingNames() {
        
        $rate = ApplicantRating::find()->all();
        $listData = ArrayHelper::map($rate, 'id', 'name');
        return $listData;
    }
```

AR.id = ARS.rating_id

The chosen value from the dropdown menu on submission goes into rating_id in ARS table.

IN THE DROPDOWN MENU I ONLY WANT TO DISPLAY VALUES THAT ARE NOT IN rating_id. So in dropdown menu if for example id 1 was chosen, i want to only display values which are not id 1; where id != rating_id

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _VALUES THAT ARE NOT IN rating_id_ how do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `not` statement in ActiveQuery is `['not', [columnName => value]]`

So I suppose you should do this like this:

> `Model::find()->where(['not', ['id', $rating_id]])->all();`